# Creating a table with maths symbols

Tags: tables, math-mode

I have a problem with the table below. I tried to fix it but it still gives the same error. I get this error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ \textbf{\rho (kg/m^{3})} and !
Extra }, or forgotten $.<recently read> \egroup \textbf{\rho
(kg/m^{3})}
```

Table:

```
 \begin{center} \textbf{Table4-1: Parameters used}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{\rho (kg/m^{3})} & \textbf{W (m)}  & \textbf{H (m)} & \textbf{L (m)} & \textbf{E (N/m^{2})} & \textbf{m (kg/m)} \\ \hline
2500 & 0.3 & 0.3 & 4 & 30x10^{9} & 225  \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: `m^3` and `\rho` can be used only in math mode. I suggest you use `siunitx`and its `\si` command to typeset units.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  first of all, `\rho` is math, not text.  so is a superscript -- `^3` -- although `\textsuperscript` is also possible.  all math needs to be properly identified.  a good introductory book might help; nicola talbot's "LaTeX for Complete Novice " at http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/index.html is such a one.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `makecell` and  `siunitx`. The former allows for a common formatting of column heads anf gives tools for some vertical padding of rows. The latter has macros for a conistent formatting of numbers (`num` command) and units (`\si`command):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{makecell, caption, chngcntr} %
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath}

\captionsetup{font=bf}
\usepackage{siunitx} %
\sisetup{detect-all}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\renewcommand\thetable{\thesection-\arabic{table}}

\begin{document}%

\setcounter{section}{4}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Parameters used}\setcellgapes{5pt}\makegapedcells
  \centering%
  \begin{tabular}{|*{6}{c|}}
    \hline
    \thead{$\rho$ (\si{\kg/m^{3}}) }& \thead{W (m)} & \thead{H (m}) & \thead{L (m)} & \thead{E (\si{\N/\m²}}) & \thead{m (\si{kg/m})} \\
    \hline
    2500 & 0.3 & 0.3 & 4 & \num{30e9} & 225 \\ %
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all I assume you are trying to make the top row of the table equations. In this case you need to use \mathbf instead of \textbf.

Here is the table with the corrections:

```
\begin{center} 
\textbf{Table4-1: Parameters used}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$\mathbf{\rho(kg/m^{3})}$ & $\mathbf{W (m)}$  & $\mathbf{H (m)}$ & $\mathbf{L (m)}$ & $\mathbf{E (N/m^{2})}$ & $\mathbf{m (kg/m)}$ \\ 
\hline
2500 & 0.3 & 0.3 & 4 & 30x$10^{9}$ & 225  \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: I got exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

If you want the entire table to be typeset in math mode by default, you can replace the `tabular` with an `array`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{siunitx} %
\sisetup{detect-all, detect-display-math}

\begin{document}%
\setcounter{section}{4}
\begin{table}
  \caption{Parameters used}
  \[
  \begin{array}{|*{6}{c|}}
    \hline
    \boldmath \rho\ (\si{kg/m^2}) & \boldmath W\  (\si{m}) & \boldmath H\ (\si{m}) & \boldmath L\ (\si{m}) & \boldmath E\ (\si{N/m^2}) & \boldmath m\ (\si{kg/m}) \\
    \hline
    2500 & 0.3 & 0.3 & 4 & \num{30e9} & 225 \\ %
    \hline
  \end{array}
  \]
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: math mode table]

Answer (score 0):

You may wan't to take a look at my table containing math symbols.
I don't know if there is a better way where you do not have to put the `$` in every single cell, but this works.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

[...]


\section*{Aufgabe 1.4}


\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|c|c|c|l}
$\delta$ & 0           & 1           & B               &                            \\ \hline
$q_0$    & $(q_0,0,R)$ & $(q_0,1,R)$ & $(q_1,B,L)$     &    \\
$q_1$    & $(q_2,0,L)$ & $(q_2,1,L)$ & $(\bar{q},B,N)$ &    \\
$q_2$    & $(q_3,1,L)$ & $(q_3,0,L)$ & $(\bar{q},1,N)$ &    \\
$q_3$    & $(q_3,0,L)$ & $(q_3,1,L)$ & $(\bar{q},B,R)$ & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image: Table with math symbol]

Comment: I don't know how relevant your answer is to the OP, but the `array` environment is basically a math mode version of `tabular`, so in your example you can use `\[\begin{array}{l|c|c|c|l} ... \end{array}\]` and no longer need all of the `$`s.